# Why is my recursive grep not working?

Tags: linux, terminal, ubuntu-12.04, grep

I am in a parent directory and want to search for any ODT files (LibreOffice Writer) that contain the phrase "GWT" in them.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 desktop. From the terminal:

```
myUser@myMachine:~/sandbox$ pwd
/home/myUser/sandbox
myUser@myMachine:~/sandbox$ ls
cloudflip  doctrang  eclipse   lookslike  scripts       squirrel  warlib
```

All these file system objects (`eclipse`, `scripts`, etc.) are folders.

```
myUser@myMachine:~/sandbox$ grep -i -r "GWT" *.odt
grep: *.odt: No such file or directory
```

Where am I going arye here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `grep -i -r "GWT" \*.odt`
Since odt files are not plain text, I'm not really sure of the results accuracy.

Comment: Thanks @Fiisch (+1) - however same result with your suggestion...

Comment: You are instructing grep to recursively search all directories with names ending in `.odt`, *not* to recurse through all directories and search only files ending with `.odt`.

Comment: Thanks @n.st (+1) - so....how do I do what I want it to do (see the first sentence of my question)?

Comment: n.st is right; I made a mistake, sorry :)
this should do the trick `find -name *.odt | xargs grep -i "GWT"`

Comment: @Fiisch You actually don't have to switch to `find` to solve this.  `grep` offers some useful options for its recursive search.  See `--include`, `--exclude`, and `--exclude-dir` in the `man` page.  For example: `grep -R --include '*.odt' -i 'GWT' *`

Comment: OR alternatively an even simpler variant - find -name *.odt -exec grep -i "GWT" {} +

Comment: Yup, I know. Choice depends on what you are accustomed to. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ODT files are actually Zip files (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957212/how-does-open-office-compress-its-files) you should be able to grep them with the `zipgrep` command with something like this:

`find ~/sandbox -name "*.odt" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 zipgrep GWT`

Comment: +1 for *zipgrep*, since ODT files are effectively compressed and simple *grep* won't do the trick. However, this won't show which ODT files contain the string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using Bash 4, you can do the following:

```
shopt -s globstar
grep -i GWT **/*.odt
shopt -u globstar
```

When the shell option *globstar* is set, **** recursively matches all subdirectories of the current directory. The second *shopt* command unsets the command; this step is optional.

As @vanthome points out, grepping the ODT files won't do any good, since they're actually compressed. There are two inconveniences:

1. The *zipgrep* command doesn't take more than one archive name as an argument, so you have to loop through all ODT files.
2. *zipgrep* will print the matching line only (which can be **very** long in an ODT file), so you still won't know which files contain the string.

The following might achieve the desired results:

```
shopt -s globstar

for file in **/*.odt; do
    unzip -c "$file" | grep -iq GWT && echo "$file"
done

shopt -u globstar
```

The *for* loop goes through all ODT files in all subdirectories. For each file that is found, it unpacks its contents to STDOUT. Then, *grep* searches for the desired string without outputting anything (`-q`). If a match is found, *grep* returns 0 and the command after the logical AND (`&&`) gets executed, so the filename is echoed on the terminal.